# How I can delete these lines from a csv if it contains a specific word?

Tags: python, csv, text

I have a CSV file that looks something like this:

```js
"Estimated 10:10 AM
" "10:40 AM KL1973 
" "Amsterdam (AMS)
" "KLM B738 (PH-BXB) 
"
"Scheduled
" "10:50 AM AY753 
" "Helsinki (HEL)
" "Finnair A321 (OH-LZL) 
"
"Estimated 10:49 AM
" "10:50 AM W62282 
" "Brussels (CRL)
" "Wizz Air A321 (HA-LXS) 
"
"Scheduled
" "10:50 AM OS713 
" "Vienna (VIE)
" "Austrian Airlines DH8D (OE-LGL) 
"
"Scheduled
" "11:00 AM W62272 
" "Eindhoven (EIN)
" "Wizz Air A321 (HA-LXQ) 
"
```

I was wondering how to delete a line if it includes the word "Scheduled"?

I tried to use something like this but it isnt't work (Python 2.7). No error message, it is running but do nothing:

```js
import urllib2
import unicodecsv as csv
import os
import sys
import io
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys
import re

def to_2d(l,n):
    return [l[i:i+n] for i in range(0, len(l), n)]
 
f = open('air.txt', 'r')
x = f.readlines()

filename=r'output.csv'

resultcsv=open(filename,"wb")
output=csv.writer(resultcsv, delimiter=';',quotechar = '"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC, encoding='latin-1')
 
maindatatable = to_2d(x, 4)
print maindatatable
output.writerows(maindatatable)

resultcsv.close()

open("output.csv", "r+") as f:
t = f.read() to_delete = '"Scheduled'
   f.seek(0) for line in t.split('\n'):
   if line != to_delete:
      f.write(line + '\n') f.truncate()
```

And plus 1 question.
How can i delete the first 3 and the last 3 rows in this csv file?

Sorry if this seems like a really simple question, but I'm new to python and any help in this area would be greatly appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Use regex for matching pattern

Answer (score 0):

You didn't write your code like mine: you didn't respect identation and you didn't put "with" word in front of open (file...

please Update with this:

```
>  with open("file.csv", "r+") as f:
>     t = f.read()
>     to_delete = '"Scheduled'
>     f.seek(0)
>     for line in t.split('\n'):
>         if line != to_delete:
>             f.write(line + '\n')
>     f.truncate()
```

Comment: It is working, but it broke the csv file format. 
I put these informations to A1-A4, B1-B4, etc..and i want to delete the all rows which is include this "Scheduled'.

Comment: I believe that you opened CSV File in Excel ? A1-A4, B1-B4 is excel format. Excel knows how to interpret CSV format. But python don't unless you will teach it.

Comment: Yeah, i opened it in Excel :D and with this part i made 4 columns (maindatatable = to_2d(x, 4)) and i think that if i delete a row in this csv file direcetly, it is deleting the all row which is contain the "Scheduled". How can i "teach" it to do this?

Comment: First you will remove "Scheduled" and after that you should make columns for Excel ...

Comment: There are more 3 "informations" which ones join to this "Scheduled" thats why i want delete a full row